# How do I add a directory full of Bash Scripts to the Path Variable and run them from oustide of their diretory

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, bash

Having a little issue someone might be able to help me out with.
I've created a number of Bash scripts for automating some of my common day to day tasks on my Snow Lepoard Machines. All of these scripts live in a DropBox folder that is shared across my machines.

The path is the same on all machines: e.g. `/User/myuser/Drobox/Bash\ and\ Batch/`
I've added the folder to my /etc/paths

**Path Variable:**

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/myuser/Dropbox/Bash\ and\ Batch:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

My issue is not being able to run the scripts from outside their directory.
All scripts have necessary permissions e.g.: 755

Scripts can be run when in the directory:

```
mymachine:~ myuser$ cd Dropbox/Bash\ and\ Batch
mymachine:Bash and Batch myuser$ ./uni-update.sh
Update University Repository
At revision 246.
```

But not from outside of the directory:

```
mymachine:~ myuser$ ./uni-update.sh
-bash: uni-update.sh: command not found
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must not prefix the command with `./`.

It means "Use the uni-update.sh in the current directory". You do this for commands that are not found on the path, or to specify a different version or completely different program of the same name.

Run it simply as `uni-update.sh` and you're good.

Comment: Tried that.. No luck.. Still get the same error: -bash: uni-update.sh: command not found

Comment: @Jeremy Try removing the backslash escapes from the spaces in `/etc/paths`. If that doesn't work, what is the result of `echo $PATH ; which uni-update.sh ; find ~ -type f -name uni-update.sh ; ls -l /Users/myuser/Dropbox/Bash\ and\ Batch/uni-update.sh`?

Comment: mymachine:~ myuser$ echo $PATH ; which uni-update.sh ; find ~ -type f -name uni-update.sh ; ls -l /Users/myuser/Dropbox/Bash\ and\ Batch/uni-update.sh
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/myuser/Dropbox/Bash\ and\ Batch:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin
/Users/myuser/Dropbox/Bash and Batch/uni-update.sh
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 myuser  staff  101 24 Mar 20:29 /Users/myuser/Dropbox/Bash and Batch/uni-update.sh

Comment: @Jeremy looks good so far, except that the PATH entry is clearly not recognized. Have you tried removing the backslashes from `/Users/myuser/Drobox/Bash\ and\ Batch/`, as I suggested?

Comment: @Daniel, I did.. The strange thing is that it works fine on all of my other machines. Go figure..

Comment: @Jeremy Have you tried to temporarily remove the spaces from that path, e.g. just `Dropbox/Bash`? Is FileVault activated on that machine In Terminal try `cd Dropbox/Bash\ and\ Batch ; pwd` and check to see if the output matches the path in `/etc/paths`.